# Jupyter: disable restart kernel warning

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyter 4.1.0, and I find myself making frequent use of the "Restart & Run All" feature. Every time I use that button it displays this warning:

[image]

Is there a way to disable that warning?

Comment: I feel that the accepted answer doesn't answer this question. The question mentions pressing the button which indicates it's a user interaction, not a script. The accepted answer addresses [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751120/restart-ipython-kernel-with-a-command-from-a-cell). Is there a way to disable the prompt after manually selecting "Restart & Run All", for example?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can add a cell in your notebook and using the following statements:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("<script>Jupyter.notebook.kernel.restart()</script>")
```

And the kernel will restart immediately.

Comment: Doesn't work in the Jupyter Lab but works perfectly fine in Jupyter Notebook. For people checking out this answer in context of `jupyter lab` use `os._exit(00)` instead.

Comment: Is there a solution for R kernel?

Comment: @Zuooo The key of the answer was to eval HTML/javascript expr

Comment: Works great in `Jupyter notebook`. Thanks!

Comment: But doesn't spare you from having to click the notification. :-(

Comment: Yep `os._exit()` is **not** a solution at all.  It's actually worse than the built-in Jupyter way of restarting (which this question is about), because it's custom code that wastes a cell in your notebook.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question that was stated: No, there isn't.

But you might make your voice heard [over here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6420) so they might implement it some day.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bookmark in your browser for the following code:

```
javascript:Jupyter.notebook.execute_all_cells();void(0);
```

Clicking this bookmark runs all cells without asking for confirmation.

Comment: (I think that?) this will not restart the kernel, which is a problem if the reason you are restarting is that something very mysterious has happened in the global variable scope and you need to start from a clean slate.