# Restart ipython Kernel with a command from a cell

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to restart an `ipython` Kernel NOT by selecting `Kernel` > `Restart` from the notebook GUI, but from executing a command in a notebook cell?

Comment: Not intentionally, but any command which kills the kernel process will cause it to be automatically restarted. I think IPython catches `sys.exit()`, but [os._exit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit) will make it die. This skips all of Python's normal cleanup (e.g. `atexit`), though. If you just want a way to restart the kernel from the keyboard, the shortcut is `00`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now that is definitely something I will have to check. Thank you!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As Thomas K. suggested, here is the way to restart the `ipython` kernel from your keyboard:

```
import os
os._exit(00)
```

Comment: Another possibility is to call the kernel.restart() method directly, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055462/104707

Comment: This will exit ipython in my case, not restarting it.

Comment: @azzamsa it exits and automatically restarts the kernel. The problem, in my case, is that I still have to click on a pop up message to restart the kernel.

Comment: It just exits ipython for me.

Comment: It doesn't work when I use IPython in Mac's terminal.

Comment: it doesn't save you the "ok" press on the pop-up window.

Comment: why `00` and not just `0`?

Answer (score 16):

```py
import IPython

IPython.Application.instance().kernel.do_shutdown(True) #automatically restarts kernel
```

Comment: In ipython 8.1.1. this gives ----> 1 IPython.Application.instance().kernel.do_shutdown(True)

AttributeError: 'TerminalIPythonApp' object has no attribute 'kernel'

Comment: In IPython 8 and above, kernel can be accessed via `get_ipython().kernel`, so the above becomes `get_ipython().kernel.do_shutdown()` —`get_ipython` is a global available in Jupyter notebook and Colab but not interactive python shell.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using jupyter, there's also this option:

```
%reset -f
```

This is not going to fully restart, just reset all variables, which is sometimes what we want.

Answer (score 7):

To define a function that restarts the Jupyter kernel, I've successfully used:

```
from IPython.display import display_html
def restartkernel() :
    display_html("<script>Jupyter.notebook.kernel.restart()</script>",raw=True)
```

then calling

```
restartkernel()
```

when time for the restart.

Comment: It does not restart the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print(chr(12))`.

I am not sure what this function does behind the scenes, but if you are looking for a way to hide all previous outputs (such as in-memory 'card' game), it works.

Comment: `print(chr(12))` just prints a control character called "form feed", which is unicode 0x000C (12). It doesn't do anything else.