# How to update SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, google-colaboratory

Using local Jupyter Notebook, SQLite, Pandas and Plotly I want to move that notebook to the Colab website but it is reporting SQLite version 3.22 instead of 3.30. I am using window functions available since SQLite 3.28 so have to upgrade. I tried :

```
!apt-get update
!apt-get upgrade sqlite3
```

This tells me I have SQLite 3.22. How this might be resolved?

`!apt-cache policy sqlite3` result :

```
sqlite3:
  Installed: 3.22.0-1ubuntu0.2
  Candidate: 3.22.0-1ubuntu0.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.22.0-1ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.22.0-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar Might not be the place, but do you know how to change the candidate on ubuntu as well? I had the same problem before but I bypassed it through Conda.

Comment: probably this work ...https://pastebin.com/t5AZj86d but I think google colab remove folder....I'm not use Conda

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to upgrade to the latest version

```py
!curl https://www.sqlite.org/src/tarball/sqlite.tar.gz?r=release | tar xz
%cd sqlite/
!./configure
!make sqlite3.c
%cd /content
!npx degit coleifer/pysqlite3 -f
!cp sqlite/sqlite3.[ch] .
!python setup.py build_static build
!cp build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/pysqlite3/_sqlite3.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so \
     /usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/
# then MENU: Runtime > Restart runtime ...
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version  # 3.42.0
```

Here's an [example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IkyE1tArdvg7ntka-ac1tJgp9o8TWk4R) updated for Python 3.10

A faster(pre-compiled) version from my GDrive.

```py
!gdown 1tKN1FXFRJ87nkOsEsOvfzkhT-l7bHOcH -O /usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/
# MENU: Runtime > Restart runtime
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version  # '3.42.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: Installed sqlite3 is too old.

We can capitalize on google deploying the latest Ubuntu LTS in codelab as shown below by accessing Ubuntu repositories. Dqlite team, funded by Canonical, maintains a ppa for dqlite which has a dependency for the latest stable sqlite3. We can upgrade sqlite3 with three lines.

```
!sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:dqlite/stable
!sudo apt update
!sudo apt-get install -y sqlite3
```

Codelab environment

```
!lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

https://dqlite.io/docs/faq
https://launchpad.net/~dqlite/+archive/ubuntu/stable

Problem 2: Codelab has already loaded sqlite3 into memory

```
!lsof -p `ps -ef | grep ipykernel_launcher | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`  | grep sql
python3 131 root  mem       REG                7,0          2359698 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 (path dev=0,46)
python3 131 root  mem       REG                7,0          5772741 /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so (path dev=0,46)
```

As shown here, libsqlite3 is loaded into memory. Python3 interpreter will not be able use the newly installed sqlite3 unless the python process is restarted

Method 1: Kill the Python. 
Crash the runtime kernel and juypter notebooks will restart it.

```
!sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:dqlite/stable
!sudo apt update
!sudo apt-get install -y sqlite3
!sqlite3 --version
import sqlite3
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version_info)
### 
!kill `ps -ef | grep ipykernel_launcher | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'; /usr/bin/python3 -m ipykernel_launcher -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-*.json`
###
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version_info
```

Method 2: Exit the kernel - best solution

```
!sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:dqlite/stable
!sudo apt update
!sudo apt-get install -y sqlite3
!sqlite3 --version
import sqlite3, os
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version_info)
os._exit(00)
import sqlite3
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version_info)
```

[Restart ipython Kernel with a command from a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751120/restart-ipython-kernel-with-a-command-from-a-cell)

Answer (score 0):

You can install the SQLite binary directly from [pysqlite3](https://github.com/coleifer/pysqlite3) module. Takes less than 5 seconds to install and import.

```
from time import process_time
start_time = process_time()
import subprocess
try:
    import google.colab # if colab exists, install pysqlite-binary
    subprocess.run(['pip', 'install', 'pysqlite3-binary'], capture_output=False)
    import pysqlite3 as sqlite3

except ModuleNotFoundError:
    pass
end_time = process_time()

print(f'Time to install (sec): {round(end_time-start_time, 3)}')
print(f'SQLite version: {sqlite3.sqlite_version}')
```