# Pandasql not working when I add an analytical function

Tags: pandasql

I'm having an issue with the pandasql library. The library works great until I attempt an analytical function in which case I get the error:

```
**Error message**
OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

The table and code used is as follow:

```
question_id, average
ksjhf          324
9nsof          245
oi2hf          674
```

```
from pandasql import sqldf
 
q1 = """SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY question_id ORDER BY average) AS question_number FROM ordered"""

sqldf( q1 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandasql` uses a `sqlite` in memory database by default. `sqlite` only supports analytic functions as of version 3.25.0.  You must upgrade `sqlite`.  If you're in a Google Colab notebook, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427642/upgrading-sqlite-in-colab) should do it.  Be sure to restart your runtime.

If you're not using Colab, using a later version of Python would be the easiest way to go if that's an option.