# Kernel in JupyterLab keeps dying when using sys module

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I've recently started to code and wanted to try my luck on a beginners program after 10 hrs of Udemy courses.

I've coded a "Guess the number" minigame, where a number is generated between 1-10 and I want the program to restart if someone guesses wrong.

```
import random
import os
import sys

def restart_program():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)

number = str(random.randrange(1,10))

choice = input("Which number did the PC pick?\n")

if choice == number:
    print("You won!")
    restart_program()
elif choice != number:
    print("You lose!")
    restart_program()
```

For some reason JupyterLab' kernel keeps dying on me the second I input a number.

I've tried restructuring the code and using completely different code but I always kill the kernel.

Can someone tell me if I did smth wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you clarify, what exactly do you mean by dying on you? What is the specific error message you receive?

Comment: Hey, so the error message I receive is: "The kernel for *PATH* appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is not a good idea to spawn a new Python interpreter as means of "restarting" program, especially if you are not its owner (did you spawn the program in the first place? No, a Jupyter kernel did it for you → you should not try to kill it and replace by another process as `os.execv` does).

Also, depending on what is in `sys.argv` you may actually invoke a different module which also could lead to a crash. See it for yourself - when running a notebook with IPython kernel `sys.argv` contains IPython internal commands, you should not play with those!

For this simple beginner program you probably should use a loop:

```
import random

done = False

while not done:
    number = str(random.randrange(1,10))
    choice = input("Which number did the PC pick?\n")

    if choice == number:
        print("You won!")
    elif choice != number:
        print("You lose!")

    if choice == 'x':
        done = True
```

But if you really need to restart the kernel you should use one of the solutions for [restarting IPython kernel from code cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62744676/6646912) (or equivalent for any other kernel that you may be using).

Comment: Really appreciated. It worked. And I honestly forgot loops were a thing, no idea why I wanted to do it the hard way lmao.