# automatically clear notebook output on close in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab

Is there a default setting in Jupyter Lab to clear output for an entire notebook upon file closure?

Or a bit of code I could run early in the NB with import statements or similar. (I have some NBs where I don't run every cell every time I open).

My current workflow is to manually clear before save and exit, but I just encountered a repo commit where I'd forgotten to do that and I had a bit of an adrenaline spike as I flashed back to a corrupted notebook last year.

My interest is *preventing* potential problems and minimizing user-executable steps to do so.  I'm not interested in stripping from the command line post-hoc.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816237/ipython-notebook-clear-cell-output-in-code) thread just clears individual cells.

I'm somewhat intrigued by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751120/restart-ipython-kernel-with-a-command-from-a-cell) but, without spending more time on it, not clear how much effort it would take to incorporate into my GitKraken flow.

[This](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout) also seems promising, but again is on the back side of things.

Figured I'd check if I'm missing something much more fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using jupytext and convert my notebooks to `markdown` format, so whenever I close them, the outputs are cleared automatically.
https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: looks promising...cheers!