# Restart Kernel and Deal with the Pop Up in Command Line in Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I want to restart kernel in command line in Python jupternotebook and this code works well
[Restart ipython Kernel with a command from a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751120/restart-ipython-kernel-with-a-command-from-a-cell)

```
import os
os._exit(00)
```

However, there is a pop up message like this which I need to click -

[image]

Is there a code to avoid this manual code for clicking?